# Finding gradient of an unknown function at a given point in Python

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, gradient-descent

I am asked to write an implementation of the gradient descent in python with the signature `gradient(f, P0, gamma, epsilon)` where f is an unknown and possibly multivariate function, P0 is the starting point for the gradient descent, gamma is the constant step and epsilon the stopping criteria.

What I find tricky is how to evaluate the gradient of `f` at the point `P0` without knowing anything on `f`. I know there is `numpy.gradient` but I don't know how to use it in the case where I don't know the dimensions of `f`. Also, `numpy.gradient` works with samples of the function, so how to choose the right samples to compute the gradient at a point without any information on the function and the point?

Comment: You can try the method of finite differences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Comment: You write "how to choose ... without any information on the function and the point?", but you start with defining "P0 is the starting point"

Comment: Yes sure, but if I understand correctly (and I am not sure) `numpy.gradient` does not take the function as a parameter but samples of the function at some points to approximate the gradient. So how can i choose a generic set of samples each time I need to compute the gradient at a given point? And how to do it properly with Python?

Comment: It's unclear to me what is now known about the function and what is not. Is it really a function in the math-sense? Does the dimension of calling the *function* change from call to call? Or should your implementation just be able to handle all kind of a-priori known dimensions?

Comment: Sorry if I made it unclear. Yes it is a mathematical function, I just need generic method for computing its gradient because I don't know its dimensions.

Comment: Still unclear. Think about the questions in my comment and try to be precise. And without assumptions there is nothing you can do.

Comment: "Does the dimension of calling the function change from call to call?" No, because it is a mathematical function. "Or should your implementation just be able to handle all kind of a-priori known dimensions?" Yes

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming here, `So how can i choose a generic set of samples each time I need to compute the gradient at a given point?` means, that the dimension of the function is fixed and can be deduced from your start point.

Consider this a demo, using scipy's [approx_fprime](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html#scipy.optimize.approx_fprime), which is an easier to use wrapper-method for numerical-differentiation and also used in scipy's optimizers when a jacobian is needed, but not given.

Of course you can't ignore the parameter epsilon, which can make a difference depending on the data.

(This code is also ignoring optimize's args-parameter which is usually a good idea; i'm using the fact that A and b are inside the scope here; surely not best-practice)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime, minimize
np.random.seed(1)

# Synthetic data
A = np.random.random(size=(1000, 20))
noiseless_x = np.random.random(size=20)
b = A.dot(noiseless_x) + np.random.random(size=1000) * 0.01

# Loss function
def fun(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b, 2)

# Optimize without any explicit jacobian
x0 = np.zeros(len(noiseless_x))
res = minimize(fun, x0)
print(res.message)
print(res.fun)

# Get numerical-gradient function
eps = np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)
my_gradient = lambda x: approx_fprime(x, fun, eps)

# Optimize with our gradient
res = res = minimize(fun, x0, jac=my_gradient)
print(res.message)
print(res.fun)

# Eval gradient at some point
print(my_gradient(np.ones(len(noiseless_x))))
```

Output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
0.09272331925776327
Optimization terminated successfully.
0.09272331925776327
[15.77418041 16.43476772 15.40369129 15.79804516 15.61699104 15.52977276
 15.60408688 16.29286766 16.13469887 16.29916573 15.57258797 15.75262356
 16.3483305  15.40844536 16.8921814  15.18487358 15.95994091 15.45903492
 16.2035532  16.68831635]
```

Using:

```
# Get numerical-gradient function with a way too big eps-value
eps = 1e-3
my_gradient = lambda x: approx_fprime(x, fun, eps)
```

shows that eps is a critical parameter resulting in:

```
Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
0.09323354898565098
```

Comment: `scipy.approx_fprime` is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!
But why not choosing the minimum float value for epsilon everytime? What 
 could be a good generic epsilon?

Comment: And I precise that the _So how can i choose a generic set of samples each time I need to compute the gradient at a given point?_ was meant for `numpy.gradient` wich needs samples of the function instead of the executable function. I hope that is clear now! ;)

Comment: You can use bigger epsilons if you a-priori know what kind of accuracy you need. In other cases, yeah, follow [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815113/is-there-a-general-formula-for-estimating-the-step-size-h-in-numerical-different) (i actually did not incorporate some sqrt).

Comment: Does `scipy.approx_fprime` also works on function that takes matrices as an input? Because I get this error:
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,1682) (6,) `

Comment: Flat 1d-input-vectors only. This is the core design-decision in scipy's minimize module! If your function works naturally on matrices, you can reshape in it's first line.

Comment: What? [Reshaping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)? That's basic numpy-usage.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this so if you can please kindly share the knowledge I would be thankful to you.

Comment: I mean, `f` take for input a matrice, how could I make it take a vector without rewriting it? It seems to me that I cannot wrap it in this case.

Comment: That's too broad. Without seeing code it's hard to grasp questions like these. It seems you just need to add another wrapper-function which will take a matrix, flattens it and call the other function taking a vector. You could even do this in a one-line using lambdas.

Comment: For the code it just uses the signature of `gradient` above, `f` is a function that takes matrices, and `P0` is a matrix. 
In that function I'd like to compute the gradient of `f` at point `P0`.

Comment: A signature is not code. P0 could be list of lists, np.matrix, np.array, scipy.sparse matrix and co. Reading numpy's reshape docs and my comment about a wrapper, you should be able to do this in a few mins with your knowledge about all the types and dimensions in play.

Comment: I think I've got it, I was thinking the wrong way about it. I didn't have the mechanic for it!